# Add Column header to JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to add header Grouping to my JqGrid.Simple header Grouping is very simple But i want to Group first and last column of my grid.According to documentation we have to tell the total number of column to be grouped and these column should be at next to each other.

In my case i have 2 column to be grouped and these columns are not next to each other and Sortable Column is not Allow in my case.
Here is the [link](http://www.4shared.com/photo/zZvGpcmCce/Capture.html) of Screen shot